# Downloading all pdf files from google scholar search results using wget

Tags: unix, wget, web-crawler

I'd like to write a simple web spider or just use `wget` to download pdf results from google scholar. That would actually be quite a spiffy way to get papers for research.

I have read the following pages on stackoverflow:

[Crawl website using wget and limit total number of crawled links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973152/957560)

[How do web spiders differ from Wget's spider?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762235/957560)

[Downloading all PDF files from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9744570/957560)

[How to download all files (but not HTML) from a website using wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8755229/957560)

The last page is probably the most inspirational of all. I did try using `wget` as suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8755229/957560).

My google scholar search result page is [thus](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=liquid%20films%20pdf&btnG=&as_sdt=1,23&as_sdtp=) but nothing was downloaded.

Given that my level of understanding of webspiders is minimal, what should I do to make this possible? I do realize that writing a spider is perhaps very involved and is a project I may not want to undertake. If it is possible using `wget`, that would be absolutely awesome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
wget -e robots=off -H --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" -r -l 1 -nd -A pdf http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=filetype%3Apdf+liquid+films&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C23
```

A few things to note:

1. Use of filetyle:pdf in the search query
2. One level of recursion
3. -A pdf for only accepting pdfs
4. -H to span hosts
5. -e robots=off and use of --user-agent will ensure best results. Google Scholar rejects a blank user agent, and pdf repositories are likely to disallow robots.

The limitation of course is that this will only hit the first page of results. You could expand the depth of recursion, but this will run wild and take forever. I would recommend using a combination of something like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and wget subprocesses, so that you can parse and traverse the search results strategically.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately my terminal window crashes and shuts down when I run this command. I am not running Mozilla 5.0... it is firefox 15.. so should I make some changes accordingly? I changed `firefox 3.0.3` to `firefox 15` but to no avail.

Comment: It could be the line continuations (\). Edited to remove them - try again. User agent can be whatever you like…

Comment: I get `ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.`